# Url won't change on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, scroll

As a beginner developer I'm trying to make a portfolio. I've added a little bit of code so that url changes on scroll. Active class also depends on this. Now while my code works fine on localhost, it stopped working after I uploaded it. I'd really appreciate some help. Code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

//smoothscroll
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
});
});
$(document).bind('scroll',function(e){
$('section').each(function(){
    if (
       $(this).offset().top < window.pageYOffset + 10
     && $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > window.pageYOffset + 10
    ) {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
    }
});
});
function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('.sidebar a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('.sidebar ul li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
}
```

and this is the [website](http://devin-watson.com):

Comment: That site works as you described for me. Maybe it hadn't gone through the server yet? Or browser caching?

Comment: okay, interesting... so url changes and the menu items get activated as you scroll?

Comment: Yes. Try CTRL+F5. Or if you're in Chrome you can open the dev tools, then click and hold on the browser's refresh button. That'll open a little menu which allows you to "Empty Cache and Hard Reload."

Comment: alright, guess it was my browser. i ve just cleaned it and now it's okay. thanks anyway.